# Battery grip for sony cameras

Tags: sony, sony-nex, battery-grip

is there any battery grip for Sony NEX-F3 cameras?

I've searched a lot and all I find is battery grips for other sony cameras

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason is that the NEX-F2's card slot is under the bottom, so a grip would have to either:

- leave space for card access (and so would not have much space for batteries)
- completely lock up the card access.

So a hard to design thing for a rather limited market...

Further research points to some OwnUser taiwanese company that made [grips for the NEX-3/5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDyKeNC1CD0) (and these were not really "grips" since they didn't include a shutter button) but it domain name is currently for sale.

Other NEX owners extend the battery capacity with [home-build battery packs connected to the camera using the dummy battery from a cheap DC coupler](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3482878)(*).

(*) If your only problem is battery life and you aren't too far from an AC source, a DC coupler could also be a solution.

Comment: so there is no battery grip for this camera ?

Comment: See augmented answer.